# I can't open a pdf file on Windows 10 that I downloaded by wget by WSL

Tags: wget, pdf, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to download a pdf file from a password-protected website. To do so I use `wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user="username" --http-password="password" "url_to_pdf"`. Apparently, it connects to the server properly and the document is downloaded as I get the following response:

```
--2022-09-02 13:14:51--  https://moodle.lmu.de/pluginfile.php/1568574/mod_label/intro/ex2_2022.pdf
Resolving moodle.lmu.de (moodle.lmu.de)... 129.187.255.141, 2001:4ca0:0:103::81bb:ff8d
Connecting to moodle.lmu.de (moodle.lmu.de)|129.187.255.141|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 303 See Other
Location: https://moodle.lmu.de/user/policy.php [following]
--2022-09-02 13:14:52--  https://moodle.lmu.de/user/policy.php
Reusing existing connection to moodle.lmu.de:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘ex2_2022.pdf.1’

ex2_2022.pdf.1                    [ <=>                                              ]  75.64K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s

2022-09-02 13:14:52 (531 KB/s) - ‘ex2_2022.pdf.1’ saved [77453]
```

But the problem is that when I enter the directory from the Windows file manager and try to open it with Adobe Acrobat I get the following error:
[image: Adobe error]

I use Windows 10, WSL and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Wget output carefully, you can see that the "PDF" file that you're trying to download is a redirect to a web page (https://moodle.lmu.de/user/policy.php). Look at this line in your output:
`Length: unspecified [text/html]`. You're downloading a HTML file. No wonder Adobe Acrobat can't read it. If you're not convinced, try looking at the file in Notepad, and you'll probably see HTML code!

Comment: Ohh, that's true. Thank you for noting that. So how could I download a file from a password protected webpage when the link redirects to another webpage?

Comment: @PawełKorzeb Is the webpage *really* using HTTP authentication?  That's the only way that the `wget` command will work (and it *should* handle redirects in that case).  If it's using form-based authentication, however, you'll need a different mechanism -- Probably something like logging in from your browser, saving the cookies, and using the session cookie with `wget`.  See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6924582/11810933).

Comment: thanks, that helps!!